# Map Java field to JSON document root

Tags: java, json, jackson

I couldn't find an example how to map the following json:

```
{
"id":1,
"name":"hugodesmarques",
"age":30,
}
```

To the following java object using jackson:

```
public class EntityDto {
   private Map<String, Object> content;
}
```

Notice the dto is just a wrapper. What I'm trying to achieve is to have an object EntityDto with a Map{name=>"hugodesmarques", age=>30, id=>1}.

I want to avoid having to map each json field to an object map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A step back

First of all, the JSON you posted in you question is *invalid*: there's a comma after `30` and it shouldn't be there. Fix your JSON otherwise Jackson won't parse it:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "hugodesmarques",
  "age": 30
}
```

### Parsing the JSON with Jackson

Add a constructor annotated with [`@JsonCreator`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) to the `EntityDto` class, as following:

```
public class EntityDto {

    private Map<String, Object> content;

    @JsonCreator
    public EntityDto(Map<String, Object> content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

Then parse the JSON using [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html):

```
String json = "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"hugodesmarques\",\"age\":30}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
EntityDto entityDto = mapper.readValue(json, EntityDto.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, my mistake I wrote the example json specifically for the question.

I'll try your suggestion and I'll let you know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Structure of class must be like structure of JSON:

```
public class EntityDto {
   int id;
   String name;
   int age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jackson can read JSON as a HashMap:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue("{\"id\":1, \"name\": \"One\"}", HashMap.class);
    EntityDto dto = new EntityDto();
    dto.setContent(map);
```